# How to log out of Stack Exchange

Tags: support

Is there a way to log out of Stack Exchange?  Or does each community have its own log out?

I haven't found a way to log out in any of my accounts or the help page.

Comment: Top-left corner there's a dropdown that says StackExchange. Click it and find the log out link near the top-right.

Comment: @zondo You should post your comment as an answer so that Aidan can accept it.